# Hibernate not running after I change user

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'performanceDao' defined in class path
>   resource [dao-bean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open
>   connection    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:623)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:862)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.BootstrapWrapper.start(BootstrapWrapper.java:306)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.BootstrapWrapper.run(BootstrapWrapper.java:517)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

When I run my tomcat server from admin user, I dont see these errors but when I run tomcat from some non-admin (non-root) user I get these errors.

Where should I look to resolve these issues

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think rebuild will work for you, but not sure

Comment: Whether your domain class having default constructor?

Comment: @Suganthan: any idea how it might help ?
thanks again

Comment: @Suganthan : not sure what domainclass you are referring to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you connect to the DB? using the credentials of the user who logged into the tomcat? If so, check the permissions of the user who logged in with the DB, he may not have permissions to access the DB. based on your error.

Comment: I connect to db through java code using hibrenate.properties, which has the username and password for db

Comment: The property file remains the same for both the user :(

Comment: guess is the .properties file is not accessible for this user. Is this file located in the class path? You may try to play around with the .properties file location.